# Issue on sending embedded image to gmail jquery c# mvc

Tags: image, email, outlook, gmail

I am facing an issue on sending email. Actually, I am trying to send an email with more text and many images in the body of the mail . I am using jquery and c# controller to make this work out.

The following code explains bit better:

In jquery, am using

```
$scope.SendEMailNew = function () {

    var data = new FormData();
    var ToEmail = $("#emailTo").val();
    var CcEmail = $("#emailCc").val();
    var Subject = $("#emailSubject").val();        
    var Message = document.getElementById(divID).outerHTML;

        data.append("ToEmail", ToEmail);
        data.append("CcEmail", CcEmail);
        data.append("Subject", Subject);
        data.append("Message", Message);

        mailsendingIndicator();
        $.ajax({
            url: ApplicationUrl + 'SendEmail/MailSend',              
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {

                hidemailsendingIndicator();
                toastr.clear();
                toastr.success("Mail sent successfully", opts);
            },
            error: function (er) {
                hidemailsendingIndicator();
                toastr.clear();
                toastr.error("Something went wrong", opts);
            }
        });
```

In c# mvc controller, i am using

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public void MailSend(SendEmail MailDetails)
    {         
            string result = string.Empty;   
            string from = "FromMail@gmail.com"; 

            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from,MailDetails.ToEmail))
                {
                    mail.Subject = MailDetails.Subject;
                    mail.Body = MailDetails.Message;                       
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;                                                         

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MailDetails.CcEmail))
                        mail.CC.Add(MailDetails.CcEmail);

                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";                      
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;                 
                    NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("FromMail@gmail.com", "Password");
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    smtp.Credentials = networkCredential;
                    smtp.Port = 587;                   
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }              
    }
```

After this code, the email could be sent with embedded images to my official mail id and to my client's mail id but to gmail and to outlook mails, the embedded images not displaying.

Especially, in outlook mails, I am not getting the option to download the image itself. In gmail, i am getting the image as base 64 code. Actually, the image is stored as bytes in database and retrieved to jquery through ajax call. I am facing this issue for long time.

What will be the solution for this kind of issue? Any idea will be a great help

Thanks